# Как присвоить массив?

Tags: c++, c

Я хочу в один wchar_t* присвоить другой. Чтобы это корректно сделать в принципе достаточно этого кода

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const wchar_t* str = L"hello";
wchar_t* string = new wchar_t[wcslen(str) + 1];
wcscpy(string, str);

wcout << "string=" << string << endl;

wchar_t* nextString = new wchar_t[30];

/*
* Здесь какая-то логика
*/

delete[] nextString;
nextString = string;

wcout << "Next string=" << nextString << endl;

/*
* Здесь какая-то логика
*/

delete[] nextString;
return 0;
}

===Output===
string=hello
Next string=hello
```

Допустим мне лень каждый раз писать двухстрочную конструкцию с `delete[]` и я создал функцию `assign`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

void assign(wchar_t* source, wchar_t* destination)
{
delete[] destination;
destination = source;
}

int main()
{
const wchar_t* str = L"hello";
wchar_t* string = new wchar_t[wcslen(str) + 1];
wcscpy(string, str);

wcout << "string=" << string << endl;

wchar_t* nextString = new wchar_t[30];

/*
* Здесь какая-то логика
*/

assign(string, nextString);

wcout << "Next string=" << nextString << endl;
}
и теперь
===Output===
string=hello
Next string=
```

Как я понял нужно передавать не *destination, а **desstination?
Но как это корректно сделать не понимаю.

Кучу вариантов перебровыл. и `delete destination`, `delete[] destination`, `delete *destination`
кто-то может помочь?

хочу сделать акцент на том, что я хочу не скопировать данные из одного массива в другой, а прям присвоить

Comment: Немного обобщите алгоритм действий и возвращайте адрес -- `wchar_t * assign(wchar_t* source, wchar_t* destination) {delete[] destination; destination = source; return destination;}`. В вашем случае используйте так -- `nextString = assign(string, nextString);`

Comment: `wchar_t*` - это не массив, а указатель. Присваивание указателей - тривиальная операция. Присваивание массивов в С/С++ отсутствует.

Comment: @avp, спасибо вам!

Comment: @SdxSdySdz, кстати, такую функцию можно легко обернуть в макрос `#define ASSIGN(s, d) (d = assign(s, d))` и использовать в частном случае, как у вас, вот так -- `ASSIGN(string, nextString);`

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось довольно простым.

```
void assign(wchar_t* source, wchar_t* &destination)
```